# HTML Email Images

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've just been given a take home exam for a job as an email developer. My task is to try my best to create an HTML email out of a .png file. I've been using tables, and I've come to a section where I have to insert an image alongside text, and I'm crashing and burning. The header text is too far displaced from the paragraph, and the image doesn't sit well; does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve the issue? My code is as follows:

```css
       
div #costume-section {
    
    width:645px;
    height: 225px;
    padding-left: 05px;
    background: #ff821d;
    color: white;    
           
}
```

```html
 <div id="costume-section">
         <table>
             <th id="cos-font">Costume Contest</th>
             <tr>
               <td>Duhh, of course - Wear it all day if you wanna. Perhaps you will be the winner of the contest? (must be present at party to be voted on)  We'll hold a kid contest too!</td>
                 <td><img src="http://mandrill-emails.s3.amazonaws.com/melt-holidays/20151020/costumes.png"  /></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
```

[image: HTML Email Images]

Comment: Since this is a job interview question, I would HIGHLY advise you to try and solve this completely on your own. If you're struggling with it, then maybe the job isn't for you.

Comment: I was advised to  "reach out for help" whenever I needed to do so, and told that knowing "where" to reach out for help is as important to them as me  actually knowing how to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rachelledev

Think about this like you are working in a spreadsheet. You have set a `th` and a `tr` table row.

Since you have your header text outside of the row containg the 2 `td`'s the header text sits on top of the `tr` containing the text and the image.

Rearranging the table markup you don't really need the `th` in this scenario unless its a requirement.

```html
 <div id="costume-section">
         <table>
             <tr>
               <td>
               <h1>Costume Contest</h1>
               Duhh, of course - Wear it all day if you wanna. Perhaps you will be the winner of the contest? (must be present at party to be voted on)  We'll hold a kid contest too!</td>
                 
                 <td><img src="http://mandrill-emails.s3.amazonaws.com/melt-holidays/20151020/costumes.png"  /></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: The part about thinking of it as a spreadsheet really helped me to better visualize the concept. Thank you so much!